# App becomes unresponsive when opening link in child browser

Tags: android, cordova, childbrowser

When I try to open a website in a child browser the link opens fine but the app become unresponsive. It is an Android PhoneGap application and the link I want to open has a lot of content as it is a blog. I have tried clearing the cache from WebView but am still having a  problem.

Comment: Umm, i haven't worked with PhoneGap before. Are there logs in PhoneGap, like we have in Eclipse?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to open the link?